# Why doesn't the CompareStringW WinAPI call work?

Tags: windows, delphi

I work in Delphi XE2 and I have to compare two strings ignoring the diacritics. So the strings 'u' and 'ü' should be considered equal. Here is an example of my code:

```
CompareStringW(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, NORM_LINGUISTIC_CASING or NORM_IGNORENONSPACE, PChar('u'), 1, PChar('ü'), 1);

CompareStringW(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, NORM_IGNORENONSPACE, PChar('u'), 1, PChar('ü'), 1);

CompareStringW(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LINGUISTIC_IGNOREDIACRITIC, PChar('u'), 1, PChar('ü'), 1);
```

None of these gives CSTR_EQUAL which means that the strings are not the same.

What could be the problem?

I have checked these calls and the result value is not 0 so the function succeeds.

Comment: Probably the default locale (`LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT`) in your case doesn't consider `u` and `ü` to be equal. For instance, in Swedish, `a` and `ä` are two entirely different letters in the alphabet, whereas `e` and `é` are merely two different versions of the same letter.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand You were right. I have just tried it with LOCALE_INVARIANT and now it works well. Thank you!